# Move all zeros to the left with TDD approach

Tags: javascript, array, unit-testing

**The task**

> Given an integer array, move all elements that are equal to 0 to the
>   left while maintaining the order of other elements in the array. Let's
>   look at the following integer array.
>
> After moving all zero elements to the left, the array should look like
>   this. We need to maintain the order of non-zero elements.
>
> ```
> 0 0 0 1 10 20 59 63 88
> ```

**My approach**, I used TDD and hoped my solution would become just as good as the sample solution.

```
test('contains no element', () => {
  expect(moveZeroToLeft([])).toStrictEqual(undefined);
});

test('contains only a 0 element', () => {
  expect(moveZeroToLeft([0])).toStrictEqual([0]);
});

test('contains only a non 0 element', () => {
  expect(moveZeroToLeft([1])).toStrictEqual([1]);
});

test('contains more than one element with a 0', () => {
  expect(moveZeroToLeft([1, 0])).toStrictEqual([0, 1]);
});

test('contains more than one element without 0', () => {
  expect(moveZeroToLeft([1, 3])).toStrictEqual([1, 3]);
});

test('contains more than one element with a 0 somewhere in the middle', () => {
  expect(moveZeroToLeft([1, 0, 3])).toStrictEqual([0, 1, 3]);
});

test('contains random number of zeros and non-zero elements', () => {
  expect(moveZeroToLeft([1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 44, 1, 0, 2])).toStrictEqual([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 44, 1, 2]);
});
```

**My solution**

```
function moveZeroToLeft(arr) {
  if (arr.length < 2) {
    return arr;
  }
  if (arr.some(x => x === 0)) {
    let zeroCounter = 0;
    const res = arr.filter(el => {
      if (el !== 0) {
        return true;
      }
      zeroCounter++;
    });
    const leadingZeros = Array(zeroCounter).fill(0);
    return leadingZeros.concat(res);
  }
  return arr;
}
```

But the **sample solution** is much more elegant than mine:

```
let move_zeros_to_left = function(A) {
  if (A.length < 1) {
    return;
  }

  let lengthA = A.length;
  let write_index = lengthA - 1;
  let read_index = lengthA - 1;

  while (read_index >= 0) {
    if (A[read_index] != 0) {
      A[write_index] = A[read_index];
      write_index--;
    }

    read_index--;
  }

  while (write_index >= 0) {
    A[write_index] = 0;
    write_index--;
  }
};
```

How could I have come to the sample solution with a TDD approach?

Comment: ...And you're already off to a bad start: your first test case expects the wrong result! `moveZeroToLeft([])` should result in `[]`, not `undefined`. If your test is incorrect in the first place, TDD would be a hindrance to you instead.

Comment: Ah, just forgot to update the code in the question. My first impulse was indeed to return an empty array. But the sample solution returned undefined, therefore I changed the test case but forgot to update the question here

Comment: The code returns a new array, the task is to modify the existing array. It seems the tests and implementation are wrong.

Comment: It's been said in the answers but it is worth saying on it's own: the sample solution is _awful, awful, awful_. The only lines I don't have problems with are the blank lines and most of the ones with only "}".

Comment: @konijn where does it say that the function should return the existing array?

Comment: @Odalrick why exactly is the sample solution "awful"?

Comment: @thadeuszlay Two glaring problems are the unnecessary shortcut in the beginning and that is is generally unreadable. It looks like C code written in JavaScript. _I_ have more problems with it (using let instead of const, semicolons and more) but my point was mostly that the OP solution is _so_ much elegant than the sample solution.

Comment: The description (to me) clearly talks about moving the elements, not creating a new array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TDD is not for finding *"elegant"* solutions, but for finding *working* solutions that cover all edge cases. Without edge cases, solutions are often too naive and in the end won't work.

You missed some edge cases; the task states: "order of **other elements** in the array" (that are integer). How about `Infinity` and `-Infinity`? Are they numbers? :) `isNaN(Infinity)`?

Another thing is, that beauty lies in the eye of the beholder. For me elegant code, is code, that is easy to grasp and not overly complex. Whenever a problem can be solved in such a generic way, that edge case do not need any special handling this is good code. :)

Speaking of which - your problem is clearly about *transforming* an array - with JavaScript you have a good set of `Array.fns()` at you disposal and fat arrow functions. Thus I'd intuitively never use loops, but only array functions.

The original problem sounds very constructed to me - I guess some stupid code interview stuff. I guess it is about thinking of how to find zeros in an array and move them around.

However the solution is quite trivial if you are *thinking outside the box* (which you are!), that with the elements being numbers, the solution is **not** about *moving* around zeros (and thus maintain their reference, if it where not zeros but objects), **but** in *filtering* and reconstructing them.

```
const move_zeros_to_left = function(unsortedArray) {
  const numberOfZeros = unsortedArray.filter(item => item === 0).length;
  const nonZeroArray = unsortedArray.filter(item => item !== 0);
  return [...Array.from({length: numberOfZeros}).fill(0), ...nonZeroArray];
}
```

Covers all the edge cases and is *readable*. Your provided sample solution is the worst of all solution, because it neglects the fact, that JavaScript has a rich set of Array functions and thus it is neither *readable* nor *idiomatic* and I'd say thus not elegant all. :)

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "How about Infinity and -Infinity? Are they numbers? :) isNaN(Infinity)?"? That's a bit misleading to say at least. `isNaN(x) === false` does not imply x is number. Well, depends what you mean by "being a number". If you mean being of js data type `Number` then Inf, -Inf and NaN are Numbers. If you mean mathematical sense, then nor inf nor -inf nor nan are numbers. You wont find infinity on the real number line, nor in the complex plane. And definitely not in the set of all integers.

Comment: I think doing two `filter`s is not very elegant. You could compute `nonZeroArray` first and then `numberOfZeros = unsortedArray.length - nonZeroArray.length`.

Comment: Also, isn't `Array.from({length: numberOfZeros})` the same as `Array(numberOfZeros)`? Please correct me if there's a subtle difference

Comment: @Clashsoft Or just go `[...arr.filter(n => n === 0), ...arr.filter(n => n !== 0)]`, unless I'm missing some weird special case. If they're `=== 0`, aren't they always, well, `0`?

Comment: @Clashsoft Not @ChristianUlbrich, but: From a readability standpoint `Array(numberOfZeros)` is ambiguous. For example, `Array(a, b, c)` creates an array containing a, b and c, so one could expect `Array(a)` to create an array containing just `a` - which is does **unless** `a` is an integer, in which case it creates an array of the length `a` instead. So using `Array.from(...)` like this makes it more obvious what is happening. That said: In this case I myself would prefer `Array(numberOfZeros)`.

Comment: @Clashsoft **I** like my code being _descriptive_ and I find `Array.from({length: 4})` very easy to grasp. I won't argue with you over _elegance_ feel free to submit your own _elegant_ answer.

Comment: @slepic `isNaN(Infinity)` _evaluates_ to `false` and the `typeof Infinity` is `number` and I think it should be covered as an _edge case_. It is not about math, but about JavaScript (`0.1 * 0.2`). The original task is not precise enough and this is what I am alluding to.

Comment: And isNaN(NaN) is true, And yet typeof NaN is number. The task states that input Is Array of integers. That said, Infinity or NaN in the input array means the behaviour Is undefined And as such can be anything you want. Throwing error might be appropriate...

Comment: All I'm trying to say Is that you should not treat Infinity as an edge case integer but an invalid input instead. Let me prove it by saying this. For any integer `a` the following equality Is Always true `a == a`. Because Infinity does not hold this equality, it Is not an integer. It Is actualy not a number at all by the same argument.

Comment: @slepic I disagree with you and that proves to me, that the original **task** is simply not precise enough. Anyway it is not the scope of the question and both solutions - _mine_ and OP's will gracefully work with `Infinity` as input and they will also work without. But what is life without Infinity, I'd say!

Comment: I am not arguing at all against your code. Your code is not checking for infinity, it checks only for zeros or anything else and that fits well the definition of the task that is to accept array of integers and undefined behaviour otherwise. I argue that infinity is not an integer nor a number. You can think whatever you want, but this is true mathematical statement. I can give you another dozen proofs that confirm that. For example every integer is sum of two other nonzero integers. Infinity is not.

Comment: @slepic The thing is, it is not about math; it is about JavaScript: `typeof (Infinity + Infinity) === typeof (1+2)` For me `Infinity` is a `number` in JavaScript, if it is not for you - I am totally fine with that, be my guest! The test that OP wrote, were not for testing a solution for a math problem, but for a solution for a JS problem. I'd think we exchanged arguments pretty well...

Comment: It is about math, since it is about integers. In what way is integer related to javascript? There are just numbers in js and they are capable of representing a superset (+nonintegers) of a subset (not all integers are representable) of all integers. By your argument, `NaN` is also a `number`. Anyway for me Infinity is of the number type in JavaScript, but nowhere it is an integer. Anyway I would like to ask you to delete (or at least modify) the paragraph which causes all this confusion. Infinity being a number (js type) is irrelevant and misleading in context of task involving integers.

Answer (score 3):

### Testing elegance

Testing ignores the method and only focuses on the result. If however you add testing that includes criteria that focus on what you may call the elegant parts of the solution this can help you create better solutions.

Personally elegance is a fit, performant and lean, in that order.

- Fit, it *must* pass all test.
- Performant it must be as fast and use as little memory as possible.
- Lean, the code must be as compact and neat as possible.

You can test all these and iterate to a more elegant solution. However the last point is subjective and this can be hard to test. Personally I measure lean as number of lines (including empty lines) and the number of tokens used.

The last to criteria are always comparative, one solution compared to another as they have no value in isolation.

The  sample solution is in my book is far from elegant

- It is overly verbose, names too long, not using shorthand styles (short circuiting and decremented operators) contains redundant length check at start.
- Poor use of comparisons as it forces type checking for each comparison.  `>=` should use `!== 0` as its quicker.
- Has a wasted variable. There is no need for the variable `lengthA`

One can rewrite the function as

```
function bubbleDown(arr) {
    var wIdx = arr.length, rIdx = wIdx;
    while (rIdx--) { arr[rIdx] && (arr[--wIdx] = arr[rIdx]) }
    while (wIdx--) { arr[wIdx] = 0 }
}
```

Slightly faster by avoiding the type checks

```
function bubbleDown(arr) {
    var w = arr.length, r = w;
    while (r-- !== 0) { arr[r] !== 0 && (arr[--w] = arr[r]) }
    while (w-- !== 0) { arr[w] = 0 }
}
```

And slower but lean. Sucks that `Array.fill` is so much slower than a while loop.

```
function bubbleDown(arr) {
    var w = arr.length, r = w;
    while (r--) { arr[r] && (arr[--w] = arr[r]) }
    arr.fill(0, 0, w);
}
```

The first two are up to 10% faster (last 30% slower) and easier to read and maintain (if that was important as having passed all tests it never needs to be read or changed), and all 3 are elegant.

Comment: Having performant code and having compact code are often opposed to each other. One must sort their priorities for this. Also using `&&` just for the shortcut evaluation effect is less readable then you think IMO. And btw you say `>=` is less performant then `!==` and then you use the implicit bool conversion `arr[r]` as condition, which is even worse. Looks like you advocate against yourself...

Comment: Also being as fast as possible and using as little memory as possible is also often opposed to each other. You can often improve time complexity at the cost of consuming more memory. And you can often reduce memory usage at the cost of decreased speed. Again, one must sort their priorities first.

Comment: Personally, I strongly disagree with „performant and lean, in that order.“ – I much rather prefer the idiom „Make it work. Make it beautiful [i.e. manitainable]. Make it fast. In that order“ ([source](https://tomharrisonjr.com/make-it-work-make-it-beautiful-make-it-fast-three-realities-df7255a8fa09)). The burden of badly maintainable code is often larger than the burden of an efficiency problem, (and those do not even matter most of the time). I do note that beauty, maintainability, and „neatness“/„leanness“ of code are not the same and very subjective, but I'd argue they're very correlated.

Comment: @Luke Two working (fit) products all things equal the faster product always has the advantage.Good coders write perfomant maintainable code from the get go. Look at the other answer, not only does it not work (it should sort in place) it is 20 times slower. Customers notice these things, they notice fans kicking in, batteries being drained, and time ticking by. Show them the same product 20 times faster and you have a sale, not only that they come back and tell there friends, they certainly don't give a hoot about the source.